# Verb in te-form with 中に, as in "通って中に"

Tags: grammar

I have started to read a novel for practice. I came across these sentences. I can't make sense of the part *通って中に*.

> 少年はあそこ一夜過ごすことに決めた。彼は羊の群れが、壊れかけた門を**通って中に**、入るのを見届けてから、夜中に羊が迷い出さないように、何本かの棒を門にわたした。

I cannot find an explanation for the use of the combination of the verb in te-form and *chuu ni*. Figuring out this part would help me a lot to put together what the sentence says.

Comment: "あそこ一夜過ごす". Typo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

中 does not belong to the te-form 通って. The right way to parse this sentence is

> 羊が門を通って、[中]{なか}に入るのを見届けてから
>
> After [he] made sure that the sheep had passed the gate and got inside

In this case, the te-form simply joins multiple verb actions.

The comma between 通って and 中 may have confused you, however, when I google for the given phrase, I find it without the comma.

Comment: Yes, it is without the comma in the book as well. Thank you. Maybe a mistype.